# Libgdx: How to set row background in a table layout?

Tags: libgdx, tablelayout

I can't find any way to set background for row like this:

[image: sample]

I got only stack for a possible solution but that works for just one cell.

Thanks.

Edit:

I followed @tekkerue [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62225640/13600988) but dont get required result, background is still outside inner table:

[image: tried sample]

I used pixmap for background texture:

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1,1,Pixmap.Format.RGB565);
pixmap.setColor(color);
pixmap.fill();
```

Comment: I got the solution. Libgdx Table uses setRound(true)  by default. Set it to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested tables. Create a new table for each row and set the color on the row tables instead of the main one. A basic example would be:

```
// main table
Table table = new Table();

// row 1
Table row1 = new Table();
row1.setBackground(blueDrawable);
table.add(row1);
table.row();

// row 2
Table row2 = new Table();
row2.setBackground(greenDrawable);
table.add(row2)
table.row();
```

Comment: Nested table doesn't work for Labels, see edited question.